# Tengo un contador que se genera apenas imprimo, como hago para guardar esos datos por separados en una lista?

Tags: python, lista

Este es mi codigo y una pequeña parte de una super cadena:

```
Seq="AGTTGGACGAAGGTTCTGATCCCTACAGAACACCTGCCCTGAAATGGTCCCTCAGGAGAATCATCGAGGAGTTC..."

lista = [Seq[index:index+2] for index in range(0, len(Seq), 2)] 

print(dict( (l, lista.count(l) ) for l in set(lista)))
```

Esto me imprime:

```
{'CC': 50150, 'CA': 55744, 'TC': 80638, 'AC': 50200, 'TG': 53851, 'AA': 78809, 'TT': 78393,...}
```

¿Cómo hago para que se me guarde en una lista solo las cantidades en ese mismo orden para que no se me pierdan?

¿Y cómo hago para sacar trozos de esa secuencia? Es decir, que en otra lista se me guarde un trozo que comience en "AUG" y termine en "UAA" o "UAG" o "UGA" y luego en otro cajón se me guarde otro trozo que comience en "AUG".

Muchísimas gracias igual por leerlo aunque sea. <3
Soy un poco noob en hacer cosas complejas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El asunto es, ya lo tienes guardado en una lista. Eso es exactamente la variable `lista`.

Si lo que quieres es guardar una lista con los valores, puedes hacer:

```
d_valores = dict( (l, lista.count(l) ) for l in set(lista))
valores = list(d_valores.values())
```

Así tendrás en `valores` una lista con esos números, pero ten cuidado! En python iterar un diccionario no garantiza un orden concreto! Es decir, imprimir el mismo diccionario dos veces no tiene por qué dar los resultados en el mismo orden! Para garantizar que los elementos sean iterados siempre en el mismo orden puedes usar un OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d_valores = OrderedDict((l, lista.count(l)) for l in set(lista))
valores = list(d_valores.values())
```

- *y cómo hago para sacar trozos de esa secuencia*

Para eso puedes utilizar un método como este:

```
def get_part(full, begin, end):
    return full[full.index(begin):full.index(end) + len(end)]

#Ejemplo usando tu cadena de la pregunta: 
Seq="AGTTGGACGAAGGTTCTGATCCCTACAGAACACCTGCCCTGAAATGGTCCCTCAGGAGAATCATCGAGGAGTTC"
print(get_part(Seq, "GGAC", "GGTT"))
#Imprimirá GGACGAAGGTT
```